# Using this is Datepicker UI jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an `onClick` event within my datepicker and I'm trying to append `html` to the actual `td` element I select.

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
  dayNamesMin: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],
  showOtherMonths: true,
  onSelect: function(date) {

    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {

      if (date === dateArray[i].date) {

        $(this).append("<div class=\"class " + date + "\"><span>Pick a time</span><span class=\"times_available\">" + dateArray[i].time + "</span><span class=\"tickets_left\">" + dateArray[i].stock_qt + " tickets left<span></div>");
        console.log(this);

      }
    }
  }
});
```

The `html` is just: `<div id="datepicker"></div>`

Ignore all the looping all all but basically, when I use `$(this)` within the `onSelect` `this` refers to my datepicker. Not the td element I select. If I use `date` something jQuery UI gives me, it shows me the dates of the td elements I select. So I can obviously read each td, how can a append html to the td element I click on.

I tried doing an `onClick` outside of this `onSelect` but if I do, and I change months. The `onClick` event doesn't trigger.

Comment: can you please paste code with html, too.. fiddle will be very helpful

Comment: The `html` is just `<div id="datepicker"></div>` since i'm using jQuery UI. Jquery UI gives me the calendar I just need to append it to an ID. I'm just struggling to target the `td` element when I click it.

Comment: I believe you want to do something with td right.. that whole block in which td and datepicker are , can you put that section, too?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper yup, like the whole block is made by jQuery UI.There's no `html` for it other then the `div` I append it too :/

Comment: then put that div class or something where you need modification

Comment: A [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would still be useful.

Comment: A few thoughts - To bug fix have you tried adding an `alert(date);` in the function to see if it is even triggering. Also could you append something simpler as the problem could be with your append. In addition, what is in your dateArray? Your append line might not even run if dateArray is empty or you don't have a match.

Comment: Maybe this is an xy problem. Explain what you're trying to achieve by directly accessing the td element

Comment: @TJ so when you click on the `td` it'll show a drop down with data in. The `if (date === dateArray[i].date)` statement checks if the date of the `td` I click on is the same in my data. Now I can pull the correct data out, I just can't append it to the DOM. I can append it to `$(this)` which appends it to the actual, div datepicker. But I can't append it within the datepicker itself.

Comment: @SmurfEkko So you're trying to append stuff into a date, right?

Comment: @TJ yup. Exactly that. Since the `HTML` isn't there to begin with until jQuery UI is called I figured it might be something to do with that. Since I can append html to the actual div just nothing in it

Comment: @TJ thanks man! This is slightly different then I wanted. As I want to append html onto the `a` attribute instead of adding a data attribute but it's along the same lines i've been looking for. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @SmurfEkko by the way if you want to access the thing on click I've added something as an answer you can build on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery adds the table for calendar dynamically, you are going to have to jump through some css selector and filter hoops to get to the cell you want.

`.ui-datepicker-calendar td` should get you all the cells in the calendar. You can write a callback function to filter the cells by value by performing a test against the date. Once you find the cell, you can do your appending.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar td").filter(function() {
  var date = $(this).text();
  return /\d/.test(date);
}).append('Blah'); // Whatever you want to append.
```

})

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to access the clicked `<td>`, you can hack as shown below. Note that's it's a hack based on undocumented properties so it might break with future releases.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date, instance) {
      var data = date.split('/');
      var month = data[0] < 10 ? data[0].charAt(1) - 1 : data[0] - 1;
      var day = data[1] < 10 ? data[1].charAt(1) : data[1];
      var year = data[2];
      var $table = instance.dpDiv;
      var td = $table.find('tbody td').filter(function(i, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var $a = $el.find('a');
        return ($a.text() == day && $el.data('month') == month && $el.data('year') == year);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```